# Find function $f$ such that $f(1) = 1$ and $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + \left\{ f(x) \right\}^2}.$

Tags: real-analysis

This was actually from my recent exam questioning :

Prove
$$f(\sqrt3) < 1 + \frac{\pi}{12}$$
for function $f$ such that $f \in C(1, \infty), \:f(1) = 1$ and $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + \left\{ f(x) \right\}^2}.$$

The solution is :

Since $f'(x) > 0$, $f$ is an increasing function in $(1, \infty)$ and $f(x) > f(1) = 1$ where $x > 1.$

Therefore,
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + \left\{ f(x) \right\}^2} < \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$$

and

$$\int_{1}^{x} f'(t) dt < \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{1 + t^2} dt,$$
$$f(x) - f(1) < \tan^{-1} x - \tan^{-1} 1,$$
$$f(x) < \tan^{-1} x - \frac{\pi}{4} + 1.$$

let $x = \sqrt3$, and we get the identity :
$$f(\sqrt3) < 1 + \frac{\pi}{12}.$$

Now I am curious if there exists $f$ such that
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + \left\{ f(x) \right\}^2}.$$

Not only about the existence, but I would also like to find the specific function if possible. Wolfram Alpha gives me the plots, but gives no hint about the specific function itself.

Comment: Yes, it definitely exists. You can show this with the Picard-Lindelof theorem. That doesn't necessarily mean it is expressible in closed form.